# Simple R Leaflet Map with Reactive - Not working - tried everything

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to show a map with the longitudes and latitudes from player and for it to change depending on the rank of the player in the slider.

Issues

- The map in the UI doesn't work (the static as shown in commented version works fine)
- The slider does not feed the inputs in the map (it doesn't react)

If you show me what I am doing is wrong, I will be very grateful.

Thank you

```r
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

a <- c("John","Tim","Ronaldo","Messi")
b <- c(4, 3, 1, 2)
c <- c(-121.890339,-121.888161,-121.892335,-121.892335)
d <- c(37.337290,37.337955,37.340215, 37.340215)

players <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
names(players) <- c('name', 'rank', 'y_cord', 'x_cord')
names

# testmap <- leaflet() %>%
#                 addTiles() %>%
#                 addMarkers(lng=players$x_cord, lat=players$y_cord)
# testmap

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Choose rank", 1, min = 1, max = 4),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("final_map")
    )
  ),
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  top_player <- reactive({players %>% filter(rank == input$obs)})

  output$final_map <- renderLeaflet(select_react <- leaflet() %>%
                                      addTiles() %>%
                                      addMarkers(lng=top_player$x_cord, lat=players$y_cord))
}


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `addMarkers(lng=top_player()$x_cord, lat=top_player()$y_cord)`

Comment: The map interface now shows but grey background/no map and points are not geocoded to the right location.

Comment: I tried the fix, and change a type of lat=players to top=player on my main program with real co-ords (this shown is only a sample code) and it works fine. Thanks!